# gcc option to ignore the libstdc++.so.5 dependency

Tags: linux, gcc, shared-libraries

after building the shared librrary using gcc, the shared library builds fine, but when i issue "ldd" it give me the dependency on "libstdc++.so.5" is there any way to tell the compiler to igonre gcc so file dependency

```
# ldd libtest.so 
            libstdc++.so.5 =>        /opt/gcc/libstdc++.so.5
            libsocket.so.1 =>        /lib/libsocket.so.1
            libnsl.so.1 =>   /lib/libnsl.so.1
            libc.so.1 =>     /lib/libc.so.1
            libmp.so.2 =>    /lib/libmp.so.2
            libmd.so.1 =>    /lib/libmd.so.1
            libscf.so.1 =>   /lib/libscf.so.1
            libdoor.so.1 =>  /lib/libdoor.so.1
            libuutil.so.1 =>         /lib/libuutil.so.1
            libgen.so.1 =>   /lib/libgen.so.1
            libm.so.2 =>     /lib/libm.so.2
            /platform/SUNW,SPARC-Enterprise-T5220/lib/libc_psr.so.1
            /platform/SUNW,SPARC-Enterprise-T5220/lib/libmd_psr.so.1
```

What compiler optiion i should give that will ignore the dependecies like "libstdc++.so.5" ?

Comment: It's tagged Linux, however it seems you are on Solaris, aren't you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> after building the shared librrary using gcc, the shared library builds fine, but when i issue "ldd" it give me the dependency on "libstdc++.so.5"

gcc doesn't automatically link libstdc++, g++ does. So, either you are linking with g++ or you pass `-lstdc++` linker option.

You have a few options:

- Build and link with `gcc`, not `g++`, to make sure libstdc++ doesn't get linked in automatically. Don't pass `-lstdc++` linker option. Obviously, this only works with `C` code.
- Build and link with `g++` and link libstdc++ statically by using `-static-libstdc++` link stage option.

Comment: # g++ -lstdc++  -o first3  first.cpp
[root@aninath-lnx sharedlibraray]# ldd first3
        libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6 (0x0000003c64600000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib64/libm.so.6 (0x0000003c5e200000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib64/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x0000003c64200000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib64/libc.so.6 (0x0000003c5de00000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000003c5ce00000)

Comment: ]# g++ -static-libstdc++ -o first3  first.cpp
g++: unrecognized option '-static-libstdc++'

Comment: Dude, you didn't like as I said. Read again.

Comment: one more thing i would like to know is can we know from the "so" file , how it is generated via g++ or gcc

Comment: @anish: `man g++` would have told you `g++ -print-file-name=libstdc++.so`